# Java Web Sockets with SSL - SSLHandshakeException - no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, java-websocket

I am trying to create web socket server in Java which can accept connections from web clients (using Https). When open URL "https://localhost:8887" in chrome, Java application throws error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common. Below are the steps I have followed.

1) First I have created a keystore using following command (as mentioned @ https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/issues/160):
    keytool -genkey -validity 3650 -keystore "keystore.jks" -storepass     "storepassword" -keypass "keypassword" -alias "default" -dname "CN=127.0.0.1, OU=MyOrgUnit, O=MyOrg, L=MyCity, S=MyRegion, C=MyCountry"

2) Below is my Java web socket server creation code:

```
public class SocketServer extends WebSocketServer {

/** The web socket port number */
private static int PORT = 8887;
private static volatile SocketServer socketServer = null;

/**
 * private constructor Creates a new WebSocketServer with the wildcard IP
 * accepting all connections.
 */
private SocketServer() {
    super(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
}

/**
 * Get singleton instance of Socket Server class
 */
public static SocketServer getInstance() {
    if (socketServer == null) {
        synchronized (SocketServer.class) {
            // Double check
            if (socketServer == null) {
                WebSocketImpl.DEBUG = true;
                socketServer = new SocketServer();                  

                // load up the key store
                String STORETYPE = "JKS";
                String KEYSTORE = "keystore.jks";
                String STOREPASSWORD = "storepassword";
                String KEYPASSWORD = "keypassword";

                try {
                    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance( STORETYPE );
                    File kf = new File( KEYSTORE );
                    ks.load( new FileInputStream( kf ), STOREPASSWORD.toCharArray() );

                    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
                    kmf.init( ks, KEYPASSWORD.toCharArray() );
                    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
                    tmf.init( ks );

                    SSLContext sslContext = null;
                    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
                    sslContext.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null );

                    socketServer.setWebSocketFactory( new DefaultSSLWebSocketServerFactory( sslContext ) );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                socketServer.start();

            }
        }
    }
    return socketServer;
}
```

Please suggest what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (Late but) JSSE does not support a privatekey entry with a keypassword different from the storepassword. Make them the same; or leave out `-keypass` and when it prompts enter nothing (hit return) to make it the same. Also, `-genkey` defaults to DSA, which not all clients support, especially in its default size of 1024; you might better specify `-keyalg RSA` and since 2014 preferably `-keysize 2048` also.